# Installation ubuntu 12.04 64 bit on notebook toshiba : no root file system is defined

Tags: 12.04, installation

When I run installation of Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on my notebook Toshiba Intel core i5, 6mb RAM, 500 Gb.

I receive a message of `"no root file system is defined"`

What can I do?

Comment: The image that you tried to enter is not having the link here. Please upload the image to a site and give the link.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to me you are not selecting a proper mount point during the installation for root ( "/" ).

Make sure you select and assign all the mountpoints according to your needs.

> > A mount point is a directory (typically an empty one) in the currently accessible
> >     filesystem on which an additional filesystem is mounted (i.e., logically attached).

Quote from http://www.linfo.org/mount_point.html